# ReactJS material makeStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have my own theme, I can theming well. 
Right now I have three different styles with material UI tabs. That's why I need to change styles using makeStyles.

This is example of tab I need to change

```
...

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.pallete.primary
  },
  tabs: {
  /// some styles
  }
...
}
));

...


<Tabs
 ...someProps
 className={classes.tabs}
>
```

element inside tab have such classes:

```
 <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorSecondary Mui-selected MuiTab-labelIcon">
```

I have tried to edit styles the same way as

```
... = createMuiTHeme ({
overrides: {
...some overrides
}
```

in my case:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#121D42",
   MuiButtonBase: {
    root: {
    ///some styles
    },
   }
  },
...
```

but it doesn't work with makeStyles

So how can I edit buttons inside tabs using makeStyles(), is it possible? Or help me with solution please

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for now.

Using Styled Components and with creating a styled element - we can change styles easier. We should **StylesProvider**

```
const NewButton = styled(({styledComponentProp, ...rest}) => (
  <Button classes={{label: 'label'}} {...rest}/>
))`
  .label {
    color: blue;
    font-size: ${props => props.styledComponentProp};
  }  
`



export const BlueButton = styled(props => {
  return (

    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <NewButton variant="contained" styledComponentProp="20px"> Red Labeled Button </NewButton>
  </StylesProvider>
  );
})`

`;
```

But have we any better solutions?